# Can't declare constant variable locally Error installing Artificial Intelligence a Modern Approach Code on Ubuntu Trusty Tahr - Common Lisp

Tags: variables, ubuntu, artificial-intelligence, common-lisp

Im installing the code for the book Artificial Intelligence a Modern Approach  i got here http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/lisp/doc/install.html its the lisp version im installing btw

I'm on Ubuntu Trusty using Emacs SBCL slime, I placed the code in ~/.emacs.d

so per the instructions  at above link i run (load "/home/w/.emacs.d/aima/code/aima.lisp")

which loads fine i get "T" as output

i run (aima-load 'all) that works I get "T" as output

but when i run (aima-compile) I get the  error

```
Can't declare constant variable locally special: +NO-BINDINGS+
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

I'm not sure I understand the error I read the Hyperspec on Declare and Special but that didn't help. I'm not opposed to a hack to make this work so if someone can help me reword the code or figure out if its a emacs setting or sbcl setting i could change to get the aforementioned variable declared that would be great. The error message is referring to this file /home/w/.emacs.d/aima/code/logic/algorithms/tell-ask.lisp

this section

```
(defmethod ask-each ((kb literal-kb) query fn)
  "For each proof of query, call fn on the substitution that 
  the proof ends up with."
  (declare (special +no-bindings+))
  (for each s in (literal-kb-sentences kb) do
       (when (equal s query) (funcall fn +no-bindings+))))
```

I verified all the permisions of all the files in my aima folder are set to read write for my username with my username as owner as a step to correct....but as far as understanding the error I could use help figuring out the next step one would take to debug this...The code is downloadable here http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/lisp/code.tar.gz  and its an easy install for a veteran emacs/lisp user....any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can just remove the whole declaration. It has no effect, and SBCL doesn't like it. See http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss099_w.htm for some related discussion.

Comment: @jlahd  Are you sure it won't hurt....did you look at the code?...It wouldn't be that bad if one example in the code didn't work right as long as the rest did...but I'm trying to use the code to learn so I don't want to get wrong info from the examples

Comment: @EdwardMonney, no it won't hurt, as `+NO-BINDINGS+` is already special, and is not defined inside of lexical scope of `ask-each`. The _declarations_ are hints to the compiler, and in this case it already knows that it's special.

Comment: @Svarog Thak you for that detailed explanation.  That will help me hack code better...love to hack and every little bit helps...Good day to you Sir=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using SBCL:

I tried loading the AIMA code as well, with the same problem in SBCL. Just comment out line in `./logic/algorithms/tell-ask.lisp`:

```
(declare (special +no-bindings+))
```

like so

```
;;(declare (special +no-bindings+))
```

, or delete the whole line altogether. Nevertheless, this is what I did:

```
(defmethod ask-each ((kb literal-kb) query fn)
  "For each proof of query, call fn on the substitution that 
  the proof ends up with."
  ;;(declare (special +no-bindings+))
  (for each s in (literal-kb-sentences kb) do
       (when (equal s query) (funcall fn +no-bindings+))))
```

You will still have an issue running `(aims-compile)` with SBCL. It will complain about some constants being redefined. Just look at the possible restarts and select every time:

```
0: [CONTINUE] GO ahead and change the value.
```

Do this as many times (about 6 times that is) as it needs to, and it will load eventually. This is probably happening because of AIMA's code non-standard build/compile system. This can be annoying, but an alternative is to trace the code and see why/where some files are being reloaded.

## USING Clozure (CCL):

CCL has a different problem with `./utilities/utilities.lisp`. CCL has both `true` and `false` functions predefined, therefore you have to make sure that both lines:

```
#-(or MCL Lispworks)
```

that directly precede both `(defun true ...)` and `(defun false ...)` are changed to:

```
#-(or MCL Lispworks CCL)
```

also, in the same source, modify `error` inside `for-each` macro to look like so:

```
(error "~a is an illegal variable in (for each ~a in ~a ...)"
   var var list)
```

With these modifications, CCL seems load AIMA code just fine.

## In general:

It's a bad idea to redefine constants or to somehow bypass debugger restarts. Best solution is to have `(defconstant ...)`s evaluated once only, perhaps by placing them in a separate source file and making sure that the build system picks it up only once.

Another solution found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/UdqdIQbDGt4), which entails *wrapping* calls to `defconstant`in a macro like so (borrowed from [here](https://github.com/bigos/discompiler/commit/42a3dc6b7403595ab55edac6256d0de55f2e58e8)):

```
(defmacro define-constant (name value &optional doc)
  (if (boundp name)
      (format t
              "~&already defined ~A~%old value ~s~%attempted value ~s~%"
              name (symbol-value name) value))
  `(defconstant ,name (if (boundp ',name) (symbol-value ',name) ,value)
     ,@(when doc (list doc))))
```

And then replacing all occurrences of `defconstant` like so:

```
(defconstant +no-bindings+ '((nil))
             "Indicates unification success, with no variables.")
```

with:

```
(define-constant +no-bindings+ '((nil))
                 "Indicates unification success, with no variables.")
```

If you opt for `define-constant` "solution", make sure that `define-constant` is evaluated first.

Comment: is there a way to make the continues automatic in SBCL

Comment: @EdwardMonney, I have added another section that should answer your question.